# Having images @2x @3x vs just one high-res image

Tags: react-native

According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images):

> You can also use the @2x and @3x suffixes to provide images for different screen densities. If you have the following file structure:

```
.
├── button.js
└── img
    ├── check.png
    ├── check@2x.png
    └── check@3x.png
```

However, I've found that if I simply use the largest image I have (e.g. check@3x.png) and rename it to check.png it will just work fine as the image automatically downscales. Are there any downsides to this?

Comment: @pir did you check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70361752/8079868

Answer (score 3):

## Disadvantages

- Downscaling a **3x** image to **2x or 1x** will take time and memory resources
- using **1x, 2x, and 3x** will also increase bundle size

[image]

## Prevention

- you can use **SVG** by using [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg) and [react-native-svg-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer). it will look good on every size of the screen, don't make any blurry effect and this will take less bundle size and memory resources
- if you are using **1x, 2x, and 3x** images then you must use `Flatlist`, otherwise app can crash on small devices due to memory overflow
- you can WebP image instead of PNG, It will provide you quality. you can [reduce application size](https://aleksefo.medium.com/reduce-react-native-application-size-with-webp-image-format-41bdd767a7ac). you can use [react-native-webp-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webp-format) for use of webp image like `<Image source={require('../../assets/close.webp')} />`

Answer (score 2):

Sure. The downsides depend on the native platform, of course, but certainly for iOS it's a bad idea in general. In increasing order of importance:

- A 3x image automatically downscaled to 2x might or might not look as good as your drawing.
- Downscaling a 3x image to 2x takes time and CPU resources, as opposed to just showing the 2x image which is instant and cost-free.
- Far and away the most important, displaying a 3x image at 2x pixel size is a massive waste of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally too lazy to follow **@2x and @3x pattern**, so my opinion is biased. In addition, there should be no opinion-based questions in SO.

If you have a single image purpose, then it's all fine. But if you're e.g. rendering a `FlatList` component with repeating image assets, then it's highly recommended to use downscaled images in favour for memory consumption.

Also, I prefer **.webp** format over **.png**. They take much less memory (and bandwith) and are supported since iOS 12 in React Native. Additionally, you can find 3rd party libraries for RN to support WebP in other platforms as well.

In a nutshell:

- repeated image assets must follow the pattern where they have downscaled versions due to lower memory consumption
- (external) images should be converted to WebP instead of PNG

Answer (score 0):

The downsides do exist, though you wouldn't be the first to go this route and have little to no issues. It's considered best practice though, and the potential downsides include:

- A case where the border of a @3x image is "low-pixeled". E.g. a 2px border would become hard to see when downscaled to @1x (0.66px)
- A case of small objects on the image @3x would be visible affected on @1x.
- Generally, you ship images at all three points to guard against future incompatibility issues from Android (and especially iOS.)

Note: With the dpi and points system for Android and iOS respectively, one must ensure the pictures have more detail and are not just bigger in size.
For some more info, see the React Native docs on [Images](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images) and [PixelRatio](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio)